# administration: Is it possible to populate the opportunity name with the word renewal + Date(year) in a text formula?

Tags: workflow, administration, formula-field, visual-workflow

I have a process builder and a workflow active to create an opportunity on its renewal date. I am wondering if I can create a text/date based formula that outputs the current opportunity name + the word "Renewal" + (currentYear) . to populate it as the new opportunity name for the renewal.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. here you go. "close date 275" is a custom date formula field for the new opportunity close date.

```
Name & " " & 
  CASE(MONTH((Close_Date_275__c)), 
     1, "January", 
     2, "February", 
     3, "March", 
     4, "April", 
     5, "May", 
     6, "June", 
     7, "July", 
     8, "August", 
     9, "September", 
    10, "October", 
    11, "November", 
    12, "December", "None") & 
    " " & TEXT(YEAR((Close_Date_275__c))) & " " & "Renewal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create another workflow on create event of opportunity. Use field update and use this formula

```
Name + "Renewal" + TEXT(TODAY())
```

Comment: This will not work since some opportunities will already have the word renewal + year, but it will not override - it will add it to the name. For example.
Current Opportunity Name ABC TEST Renewal 2014. With the above workflow it will be ABC TEST Renewal 2014 Renewal 2015. I would like it to overwrite with that new name based on the formula above..